# Looping Parameters in JS Functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, parameters

I am new to JS programming and wondered what the best way is to loop through multiple parameters inside a function.

As an example I would like to compute a compounded interest formula that prints out the results with a range of interest rates (var y) and different time horizons of an investment (var z).

I could get my code to work with one loop (please see below) but don´t get the hang of how I could make it work with two variables (looping through x and y). Y should have the following loop:

for ( y = 0; y >= 10; y++)

Could you point me into the direction?

Much appreciated.

```
 var futureValue = function formula (x,y,z) {

 a = x * (Math.pow (1+y/100, z)); // where x is starting amount of money(principal), y is real interest rate in %, and z is the number of years for the investment
 return a;
 }
 for (z = 0; z <20; z++){
 console.log(futureValue (10000,5,z));
}

}
```

Comment: maybe you start with correct naming of the parameters, like capital, interest rate and year

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two nested `for` loops and a nested array for the result.

The result looks like this:

> ```
> [
>     [                // year zero with no interest
>         "10000.00",
>         "10000.00"
>         // ...
>     ],
>     [               // year one with interest
>         "10100.00", // with 1 %
>         "10200.00", // with 2 %
>         "10300.00", // with 3 %
>         "10400.00", // with 4 %
>         "10500.00", // with 5 %
>         "10600.00", // with 6 %
>         "10700.00", // with 7 %
>         "10800.00", // with 8 %
>         "10900.00"  // with 9 %
>         "11000.00", // with 10%
>     ],
>     [               // year two with interest
>         "10201.00",
>         "10404.00",
>          // ...
>     ],
>     // ...
> ]
> ```

```js
function futureValue(capital, interestRate, years) {
    return capital * Math.pow(1 + interestRate / 100, years);
}

var year,
    interestRate,
    temp,
    result = [];

for (year = 0; year < 20; year++) {
    temp = [];
    for (interestRate = 1; interestRate <= 10; interestRate++) {
        temp.push(futureValue(10000, interestRate, year).toFixed(2));
    }
    result.push(temp);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Describe your variables in a loop

```
function formula (x,y,z) {
 a = x * (Math.pow (1+y/100, z)); // where x is starting amount of money(principal), y is real interest rate in %, and z is the number of years for the investment
 return a;
 }
 for (var z =0; z <20; z++){
 var x=1000;
 var y=5;
 console.log(formula(x,y,z));
 x++;//code for x on each iteration
 y++ // code for y
}
```